# JWT reject request if no token and reject in asp.net c# api

Tags: c#, jwt, backend, unauthorized

```
  services.AddAuthorization();

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
               options.DefaultScheme = "bearer";
            }).AddJwtBearer("bearer", options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = HelperLib.securityKey,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                };

                options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                    {
                        if (context.Exception.GetType() == typeof(SecurityTokenExpiredException))
                        {
                            context.Response.Headers.Add("Token-Expired", "true");
                            context.Response.StatusCode = 408; // request timeout
                        }else if(context.Exception.GetType() == typeof(SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException))
                        {
                            context.Response.StatusCode = 401; // security token signature is invalid
                        }else if(context.Response.GetType() == typeof(SecurityTokenInvalidSignatureException)){
                            context.Response.StatusCode = 408;
                        }

                        // if no token is set 
                        context.Response.StatusCode = 402; // check if bearer has token
                        Console.WriteLine($"no token has been set {context.Response.StatusCode = 408}");

                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                };
```

i am trying to add jwt authentication when the user request using jwt,
also for this i want to reject the request when the user session is expired and no token it should return 401 but for now what happen the user can request even though without token, is there any way I can do this?is policy is much better?

Comment: Do you have `[Authorize]` attributes in your controller?

Comment: Yes I have from my controller but the request with no token has access like Bearer  
with no token always 200